# windows live id web authentication sdk giving Java App server error

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, deployment, live

I'm making a website in c# .NET and using the windows live id web authentication sdk for my logins.  I'm trying to deploy the site using server 2003 and IIS 6.0, but I'm getting the following error, when redirecting from the login page to webauth-handler:

> HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL
>   type Status report
>   messageHTTP method POST is not supported by this URL
>   descriptionThe specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource (HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL).
>
> Sun Java System Application Server 9.1

This used to work fine when developing on localhost, but broke once I tried to deploy my website.  When I deployed my site I set up a new project on lx.azure.com, and added the application id and secret key to my web.config.

I'm confused by the Java error, as I have no Java application server running, and don't use Java on the server at all !

If anyone knows why this may be happening, I would really appreciate your knowledge :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with my url forwarding - it was putting a frame into my html, so the error  was most likely occurring on the domain name companies site, hence the java error.